# bootstrap carousel slider with codeigniter not working?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, slider, carousel

**help me to make the silders work :**

this my code view :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indic[enter image description here][1]ators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>   
      </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" >
        <div class="item-active">
        <?=img([
                'src'       => 'uploads/slider/' . $slider->image
            ])?>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3><?=$slider->name?></h3>
            <p><?=$slider->description?></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

</div>
```

this my controller code :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //load model -> model products
        $this->load->model('model_products');
        $this->load->model('model_sliders');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['products'] = $this->model_products->all();
        $data['sliders'] = $this->model_sliders->all();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
    }
}
```

this my model :

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_sliders extends CI_Model {

    public function all(){
        //query semua record di table products
        $hasil = $this->db->get('sliders');
        if($hasil->num_rows() > 0){
            return $hasil->result();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }
}
```

**this the result but the arow slider not work..**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPszJ.png]

help me to make the slider work i use codeigniter v2 and phpmyadmin...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Can you provide more details on what errors you're seeing in the console? When you view source on the page, is the PHP producing the HTML you're expecting?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: where is your `foreach()` loop??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this use a forech loop or for loop to list all items in database. change your `<img src="">` to `<img src="uploads/slider/<?php echo $slider->image">`. 
**In Bootstrap caurosal slider `class` of first Item should be `class="item-active"` remaining  items has class `class="item"`**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indic[enter image description here][1]ators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>   
      </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" >
        <div class="item-active">
        <img src="uploads/slider/<?php echo $slider->image">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3><?=$slider->name?></h3>
            <p><?=$slider->description?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php foreach($sliders as $slider){?>
         <div class="item">
        <img src="uploads/slider/<?php echo $slider->image">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3><?=$slider->name?></h3>
            <p><?=$slider->description?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

</div>
```